# Mysql query to print attendance sheet

Tags: mysql, sql

Please some one help me tI have two Tables in my MYSQL database,

the first table - (**Employee Table)** consists of

```
EmployeeNo| EmployeeName
```

the second table - **(Attendance table)** consists of

```
DATE | TIME | STATUS| EmployeeNo
```

and a calendar table that holds only date for every month

I want to generate attendance sheet similar to this 
[Click here](https://s27.postimg.org/g2uepwhmr/attendance.png)

I end up writing the following SQL, but it gives me syntax error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
        MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from (select cal.calendarDate, 
        emp.first_name,emp.nu' at line 2
```

and my query ,

```
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN calemp.calendarDate = ''',date_format(calendarDate, '%Y-%m-%d'),''' THEN coalesce(att.inorout, ''P'') END) AS `',date_format(calendarDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), '`'
    )
      ) INTO @sql
     FROM yearly_date_calendar
     where calendarDate >= '2016-11-01'
     and calendarDate <= '2016-11-30';

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT calemp.first_name,calemp.nurse_code,',@sql,'
            from
            (
              select cal.calendarDate,emp.first_name,emp.nurse_code
              from yearly_date_calendar cal
              cross join syscare_caregiver emp
            ) calemp
            left join syscare_employee_attendance att
              on calemp.nurse_code = att.emp_code
              and calemp.calendarDate = att.attendance_date
            where calemp.calendarDate>=''2016-11-01''
              and calemp.calendarDate <= ''2016-11-30''
            group by calemp.first_name, calemp.nurse_code,calemp.calendarDate
      ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Its not a must, if you know any other way using stored procedure etc.. or pivot , please help me

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this, I am hearing that MySQL doesnot support pivoting, so how can I do this,

Comment: I think you risk confusing data storage & retrieval with data display - the latter normally best resolved in application code (like the kind of code that generates your pretty picture).

Comment: didn't you asked the same question little ago with a different user account? Why repeating the question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140611/sql-syntax-error/41140667?noredirect=1#comment69484172_41140667

Answer (score -1):

You can use below query and fetch all database result

```
select EmployeeTable.EmployeeNo,Employee Table.EmployeeName,Attendance table.DATE,Attendance table.TIME,Attendance table.STAUS,Attendance table.EmployeeNo from Employee Table INNER JOIN Attendance table ON 
EmployeeTable.EmployeeNo=Attendance table.EmployeeNo
```

Comment: But in that way, it will take lots of time for execution

Comment: i think you can use cache your page

Comment: @AbuMirza Absolute nonsense - although an OUTER JOIN is desirable here (as opposed to an INNER JOIN)